# Python macros on Mac using Komodo

Tags: python, macos, macros, komodo

I'm using Komodo IDE, version 6.1.1, build 61234, platform macosx-x86. I'm also using Python 3.2 and Python 2.7. I've *just* moved to using (my first) Mac. OS version 10.6.?

On my Windows machines I had a couple of macros set up that I would like to continue to use:

F2: save file and then run using Python 2.x, results in tab, start in current directory
F3: save file and then run using Python 3.x, results in tab, start in current directory

Any idea how to do this? I'm very new to using a Mac so I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing my own macros - see below...

```
// Macro recorded on: Thu Jun 10 2010 08:50:50 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)
komodo.assertMacroVersion(3);
if (komodo.view && komodo.view.scintilla) { komodo.view.scintilla.focus(); }
komodo.doCommand('cmd_save')
ko.run.runEncodedCommand(window, '/usr/local/bin/pythonw \"%F\" {\'cwd\': u\'%D\'}');
```

and...

```
// Macro recorded on: Thu Jun 10 2010 08:50:50 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)
komodo.assertMacroVersion(3);
if (komodo.view && komodo.view.scintilla) { komodo.view.scintilla.focus(); }
komodo.doCommand('cmd_save')
ko.run.runEncodedCommand(window, '/usr/local/bin/pythonw3 \"%F\" {\'cwd\': u\'%D\'}');
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your 'Toolbox', right click the macro you want to save and then click 'Save as'. Copy the saved macros to your Mac. And then click the wrench icon and click 'Import files from file system'

[image]

If you have Komodo 7, then you can use [the Synchronization feature](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/sync.html) to sync your macros to multiple computers without much effort.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about Komodo 7.