# Create a New Command or Macro in Komodo 7.1 IDE to save and run a python file

Tags: python-3.x, komodo

How can I create a New Command or Macro in Komodo 7.1 IDE to save and run a python file?

I want the output to go to a New Console.  Not the Command Output Tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put:

```
import code
code.interact(local=locals())
```

in your program, then you will be dumped to a [python interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711193/komodo-watch-variables-and-execute-code-while-on-pause-in-the-program). (See [Method to peek at a Python program running right now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637198/method-to-peek-at-a-running-python-program/1637277#1637277)).

Use [doCommand and runEncodedCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172314/python-macros-on-mac-using-komodo) to save and run the python file respectively:

```
komodo.assertMacroVersion(3);
if (komodo.view && komodo.view.scintilla) { komodo.view.scintilla.focus(); }
komodo.doCommand('cmd_save')
ko.run.runEncodedCommand(window, '/usr/local/bin/pythonw3 \"%F\" {\'cwd\': u\'%D\'}');
```